# Laravel: get email recipient from within the mail template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When using Notifications in Laravel (5.5), you can access the Notifiable (the recipient) from within the `toMail()` method.

Is there an equivalent way to access the recipient when you are sending a Mailable?

Is there a better solution than just repeating the User instance in the constructor like this?

```
Mail::to($user)->send(new EventAlert($user));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way. But you can use Mailable inside a Notification class and use the notification instead of Mailable in a controller or service.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#mail-notifications):

> You may return a mailable object from the `toMail` method

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new Mailable($this->invoice))->to($this->user->email);
}
```