# Laravel - How to access $notifiable from within email template

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5

Laravel 5.5 app: I decided to customize my mail templates, so I ran the following artisan commands:

```
artisan publish:vendor --tag=laravel-mail
artisan publish:vendor --tag=laravel-notifications
```

Then I decided to edit the copyright info at the bottom of `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/message.blade.php` so I could add some links beneath that, but in order to generate those links, I need access to the `$notifiable` entity. Only problem is, I can't find any way to access it from within the template. I would prefer not to have to pass `$notifiable` to a view each and every time I send an email. But, even if I pass `$notifiable` to the view from the notification's `toMail()` method, like so:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Verify Email')
        ->markdown('mail.email-verification-email', [
            'notifiable' => $notifiable
        ]);
}
```

I still can't access it from the file mentioned above. It throws an error unless I check if the variable is set, and it never is.

I stumbled across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450809/laravel-get-email-recipient-from-within-the-mail-template) here on Stack Overflow, but I don't understand how the answer solves the issue. I think the answer is addressing a slightly different issue.

Comment: use a helper if you don't want to pass it to the view, then you would call the helper method in the view, for the not defined issue, try `php artisan view:clear` after you access the variable

Comment: `php artisan view:clear` does not change anything. As far as the helper, wouldn't the helper need to be some sort of global object? I'm not quite sure what that solution would actually look like.

Comment: are you using `Queueable` trait and queue worker is running?, if so restart it

Comment: Already tried restarting the queue worker too

Comment: I don't really work with blade much but my guess is that the view variables are only accessible from the body of the email, not the footer (etc).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it works for me

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Verify Email')
        ->view(
        'mail.email-verification-email', ['notifiable' => $notifiable]
    );
}
```